# Debugging Web API returns Resource no match error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

When I try to debug the application by calling like

```
  http://localhost:5/api/GetEmployeesDEV
```

It returns error like

`No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:57764/api/GetEmployeesDEV'. No action was found on the controller 'GetEmployeesDEV' that matches the request.`

The ASP.NET Web API which makes a Call to the Odata endpoint and returns the response received by the call. And I have the below code for the Controller

```
 public class GetEmployeesDEVController : ApiController
 {
 [HttpGet]
 private async Task<EmployeeDTO.RootObject> Get()
{
    string userName_Core = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["core_Username"];
    string password_Core = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["core_Password"];
    string BaseURL_Core = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseURL_Core"];
    var byteArray_Core = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(userName_Core + ":" + password_Core);
    EmployeeDTO.RootObject returnObj = new EmployeeDTO.RootObject();

    try
    {
        // GET
        using (var client_Core = new HttpClient())
        {
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
            Uri uri = new Uri(BaseURL_Core);
            client_Core.BaseAddress = uri;
            client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client_Core.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray_Core));

            string core_URL = BaseURL_Core;
            var response = client_Core.GetAsync(core_URL).Result;

            var responsedata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            returnObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<EmployeeDTO.RootObject>(responsedata);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

Not sure if I am missing something here. I didnot change anything with RouteConfig file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change the scope of the function

From **private**

```
private async Task<EmployeeDTO.RootObject> Get()
```

To **public**

```
public async Task<EmployeeDTO.RootObject> Get()
```

Action need to be public in order to be available for routing.